# Correct way of accessing the array id of textbox using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Can anyone help me, what is the correct syntax if the id or name of the textbox is an array?

```
<input type="text" name="txt" id="txt" value="1" />
<input type="text" name="txt[0]" id="txt[0]" value="2" />

<script>
    // Msg: 1
    alert($('#txt').val());

    // Msg: Undefined
    alert($('#txt[0]').val());

</script>
```

Thank you inadvance

Comment: `$('#txt').attr('id')` or `$('#txt')[0].id` - [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/va/) gives the *value* of the element.

Comment: you can just use `class="txt-0"` .. and select `$('.txt-0')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[]` is used for selecting element by attribute. You need to escape those, to cancel that behaviour:

```
$('#txt\\[0\\]').val()
```

Answer (score 3):

Escape special characters with `\\` [See here](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_select_an_element_by_an_ID_that_has_characters_used_in_CSS_notation.3F)

```
alert($('#txt\\[0\\]').val());
```